# Configure Eclipse to allow Tomcat connector under address other than localhost (issue with startup timeout)

Tags: tomcat7, eclipse-kepler

I'm attempting to get Tomcat running in Eclipse with an IP address specified for the connector  other than localhost. I'm running into an issue though with Eclipse hitting it's startup timeout. I get this error:

```
Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.
```

However, I can see that Tomcat has started up successfully because I get this at the end of the console output:

```
INFO: Server startup in xxxx ms
```

Additionally, if I set the timeout value in Eclipse to a value high enough to give me time to bring up my webapp in a browser under the correct IP address, it works. But eventually Eclipse will shut Tomcat down because it hits the timeout.

What I'm thinking is happening is that Eclipse is looking to see if Tomcat has started under localhost:8080 but it's not getting a response so it thinks it hasn't started yet and it eventually times out.

Is there a configuration in Eclipse to either tell it what IP address to look for Tomcat under or to turn off the timeout feature all together?

Answer (score 0):

Well, found a workaround by using Mongrel 1.0.0 plugin instead of the WST plugin that comes with Eclipse Java EE version. You can find it in the Eclipse Market place by searching for Mongrel or here is a direct link: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mongrel#.Ur3MtfRDur8

They really should look at modifying WST to allow you to specify the address you're running the tomcat connector on or have it inspect the specified server.xml for the configuration setting. I can see how it might be useful to be able to run separate instances of Tomcat which WST allows you to do but this one thing prevents me from being able to use it. Mongrel appears to be much simpler which works just fine in my case.